# what is the meaning of establishing a connection to a database? What does DriverManager.getConnection do?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I was going through the Java database tutorials and came across `DriverManager.getConnection` statement. Just wondering that what does this statement actually do behind and what is the meaning of establishing a connection with database i.e what might be the steps involved in this statement?

Comment: don't know what you want to hear now? I mean, for cummincation with something you need a connection, or not? what do you think you a computer communicates with a server? handshaking? TCP?

Comment: Here we go: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/layers.htm#NETAG206

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. just wanted to know the steps DriverManager.getConnection performs in background. I thought does this statement also initializes the underlying database application in background..? I mean thinking from the database connection perspective only...

Comment: Hm, in the worst case you could look into the source code if you're really interested about the implementation details. But in the end it's just a client/server communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we only could see the code...

Oh, actually, we can:
https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java

So, it iterates over all registered drivers:

```
for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
```

Then it calls each driver connect method with the URL:

```
Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
```

First successful connection is returned.

```
return (con);
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a database you will need jdbc drivers.

As mentioned here 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

DriverManager helps you to find and connect a suitable registered driver and return a Connection object . You can use this connection object to interact with the underlying database .

You can also define your jdbc drivers in properties file and DriverManager will load them

Answer (score 0):

Simply, DriverManager is a class and get connection is a function of that class that you are calling from your class for creating a bridge between data’s